# Numpy method returning True if the first array's values are less than the second's values element-wise

Tags: python, numpy

Given two `numpy` arrays

```py
import numpy as np
arrA = np.array([0, 1, 2])
arrB = np.array([1, 4, 9])
```

I want to implement a method that returns `True` if and only if all values in the first array are less than the corresponding values in the second one. In this case, it is `True` since `0<1, 1<4, 2<9`.

Since the arrays in actual applications are huge (about 1000 elements), it would be nice to have an efficient method.

The first attempt would be `(arrA < arrB).all()`, but it has to compute booleans in all indices. The one below uses comprehension, which I believe is the fastest one.

```py
isAllLessThan = all(x < y for (x, y) in zip(arrA, arrB))
```

Does `numpy` have any method (something like `np.all_less`) to be applied in this case?

Comment: The same in a vectorial way: `(arrA < arrB).all()`

Comment: @mozway OP mentioned that in their post, but gave a vague reason why they don't like it.

Comment: What's wrong with the vectorized way you mentioned? You say that it converts everything to booleans, but that's exactly what you do in the list comprehension.

Comment: @jared I see that, I just added a few thoughts and timings to compare the two approaches ;)

Comment: 1000 items is not huge and actually rather small. In the worst case scenario, numpy is faster starting with about 10 items. For 1000 items the running time ranges from a few μs to a few hundred μs. A signifiant relative difference, but quite fast from an absolute point of view.

Answer (score 4):

The python and numpy approaches behave differently.

Yes, numpy has to compute all combinations, but it's doing so very fast, much faster than python. Python's `all` is however able to short-circuit the test when a `False` is met.

Doing a first test in which B > A is always true, numpy is faster:

[image]

In a second test in which A = B, thus the first comparison is already False, the comprehension approach is constant time:

[image]

In real-life you're likely in between, so the best approach depends on the probability to have a False.

Here is a graph comparing the timing for various probabilities of short-circuiting:

[image]